# Artifactory: How to download a git version specified by the hash instead of a tag

Tags: git, artifactory

I set up a VCS mirror for GitHub in Artifactory. How can I download a repo version specified by its hash?

I can easily download the head of a branch by using Artifactory's REST API

```
curl -i -uuser:passw -XGET <artifactoryUrl>/api/vcs/downloadBranch/<repoKey>/openembedded/meta-openembedded/sumo
```

But when I want to download a specific ref

```
curl -i -uuser:passw -XGET <artifactoryUrl>/api/vcs/downloadBranch/<repoKey>/openembedded/meta-openembedded/aa9b1f50f424a8baee65c95a09fbb7d57c5801c8
```

I get the following error

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  
Server: Artifactory/6.7.0  
X-Artifactory-Id: 037e72e716a230b6:-414777d3:16a498a8219:-8000  
Content-Type: application/json  
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 06:50:01 GMT  
{  
  "errors" : [ {  
    "status" : 404,  
    "message" : "Unable to find ref name 'aa9b1f50f424a8baee65c95a09fbb7d57c5801c8'"  
  } ]
```

I have also tried the following with no success

```
curl -i -uuser:passw -XGET <artifactoryUrl>/api/vcs/downloadTag/<repoKey>/openembedded/meta-openembedded/aa9b1f50f424a8baee65c95a09fbb7d57c5801c8
```

Looks like Artifactory isn't supporting downloading of versions by its hash. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Try `uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant = true` in the config of the remote repository.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I do not see how this helps to solve the issue. Anyway I do not have a git repo to configure because I download the tarball.

Comment: I dont think so api supports download based on commit - the comment is not helpful but though to share.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution Update [Oct. 2023]:

JFrog added vcsDownloadCommit !

You can now Download directly a commit by hash.

```
/api/vcs/downloadCommit/github-remote/openembedded/meta-openembedded/8d6bbd050da66ad0e103c246b037c19789299dbe?ext=tar.gz
```

https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/download-a-vcs-commit

Alternatively this should also work depending on your remote configuration:

```
artifactory-url/[remote-repository]/openembedded/meta-openembedded/archive/c66ec8776ec6f467937918a114bdefa28ac036a9.zip
```

#### Update [Old]:

Interestingly enough, you can download by ref, but only if the Ref points to a Branch or Tag.
Meaning:

```
/api/vcs/downloadBranch/github-remote/openembedded/meta-openembedded/8d6bbd050da66ad0e103c246b037c19789299dbe?ext=tar.gz
```

works, because the hash actually points to a valid Branch.
Same for Tags.
If the Ref Hash points to a valid Tag, you can use the Ref Hash instead of the name.

Why downloading a specific ref is not possible at this point is beyond me. Since the structure is literally the same.

- Archives by branch are pulled from `github.com/user/repo/archive/refs/heads/{branchname}`
- Archives by tag are pulled from `github.com/user/repo/archive/refs/tags/{tagname}`
- Archives by ref hash are pulled from `github.com/user/repo/archive/refs/{hash}`

So it should be really simple to pull by hash. But apparently its not.

#### Original:

The api allowes for downloading tags. I found no way to download a specific ref, but tags are often the way to go.

If applicable, you can download specific tags by calling:

```
/api/vcs/downloadTag/{artifactory-repository}/{username/org}/{repository}/{tagname e.g. v1.2.3}?ext={tar.gz or zip}
```

replace everything including the brackets {} with your specified targets

meaning for you it would be (if they actually had any tags, which they don't):

```
/api/vcs/downloadTag/{artifactory-repository}/openembedded/meta-openembedded/{tagname e.g. v1.2.3}?ext={tar.gz or zip}
```

Source: [Download VCS-Tag - JFROG DOC](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DownloadaVCSTag)

You can find even more there. For Example downloadRelease.